# Angular wraps a component w a div

Tags: angular, css-grid

using angular 8
trying to build a form using CSS grid
I want to loop over a collection of fields and render the HTML

I have a uds-form component with this as the HTML template

I can make this work by just hard coding the HTML for 1 field.
It will show the html correctly laid out in the grid.

```
   <div  class="formgrid"  style="border:solid 3px red;">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let setting of settings; let i = index">
     
            <input type="text"
           formControlName="SampleField"
           name="SampleField"
           placeholder="Sample Field"
           />
           <label class="fieldLabel" for="SampleField">Sample Field :</label>
           <span class="fieldErrorMessage">  err msg</span>
  
            
        </ng-container>
        
    </div>
```

I am trying to use a component so I can have logic that correctly renders the appropriate HTML based on the data type of each field

```
<div  class="formgrid"  style="border:solid 3px red;">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let setting of settings; let i = index">
 
        <app-uds-form-item    [myFormGroup]=myFormGroup [setting]=setting></app-uds-form-item>    
 
        
    </ng-container>
    
</div>
```

When I do this, it wraps the HTML of the component in a div and that throws off the grid.

[image]

**My question is whether it is possible to NOT wrap the app-uds-form-item html in a parent element.**

I am open to any solution.
I am not very clear on my options w/ Angular so I am considering changing my CSS grid so it can possibly overlook the extra div.
I am also considering just joining the  form level component and the item level component. But that really seems like accepting bad design to cover my lack of understanding of Angular...

I believe a cleaner solution would be to let Angular just give me the HTML I need in the item component. Struggling with how to make that happen.

Comment: Is each item supposed to be a row in the resulting view?

Comment: Why do you need the wrapping `<ng-container>`? Why not `<app-uds-form-item *ngFor="let setting of settings; let i = index" [myFormGroup]="myFormGroup" [setting]="setting"></app-uds-form-item>`?

Comment: is there any logic in the uds-form-item component that justifies having this be a separate component?  When I've seen dynamic forms work, usually I've seen the fields looped over and a ngSwitch statement based on input type that will render the right html that way.  I would see if you can avoid using a separate component for each field and just build the dynamic fields with a ngFor/ngSwitch combo.

Comment: Here is how they show off something like this in the Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: @jakeSmith - thank you. That article is what I used to get started. They have a form component and item component. However, they use divs for each component, so my issue is not dealt with.

Comment: @Benny  - using  ng-container seems to suppress some of the components angular inserts.  This is the area I am trying to read about and understand better.  If I want to put the item logic in the form, this is what will work...

Comment: @JakeSmith - it seems like the form and the component could both grow with functionality, can't tell you what today [new input types maybe], but it seems a logical dividing line.  If I dont get a resolution today, i will move forward and combine them. I can always break them apart later if I learn the correct technique.

Comment: @majusBetter - yes, each input has a line with a label, input control, and error message. I have . https://www.sitepoint.com/css-grid-web-form-layout/  is the article i am basing my form on...for now.

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-css-grid-with-angular-96759f5378c2    example of CSS Grid.  this example has the rows defined inside the parent component, avoiding the issue [or solving it I guess...]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can not find an answer.
I am reading more on the content projection functionality in Angular.

For now, I have combined the form component and the form item component.